# GLSL behavior when dealing with non-initialized uniforms

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am creating a shader that would deal with up to, say, 10 point lights for a scene ; but I have trouble with the "up to". Here is what I want to do :

```
vec3 temp = CalcPointLight(pointLights[1], norm, FragPos, viewDir, fragDiffuse, fragSpecular);
temp *= (1.0 - ShadowCalculationPointLight(FragPos, pointLights[1].position, pointLights[1].shadowCubeMap));
temp *= pointLights[1].use;
result += temp
```

So I have an array of structures `pointLights` and I'll just do the same thing for all 10 of them, and in order to avoid branching by adding `if`statements to check if the attribute `use`is equal to 1 I multiply the result of the light / shadow calculation by the `pointLights[1].value`.

But for some reasons it seems that if the different attributes of `pointLights[1]`are not initialized, then the `result`variable (which is later sent as the fragment color) is not drawn anymore, even when the `temp` vector is supposed to be multiplied by 0.

To me there are two solutions to that problem : either I have to generate / write a shader for each number of point lights I have to deal with (so if I want to use up to 10 lights I'll have to write 11 different shaders) ; or I always initialize all of my 10 lights with values that will make my functions always return `(0,0,0)`. For the latter solution I am not sure about how to initialize a `samplerCube` such that it will contain exclusively 0s... Or is there another solution ?

EDIT : I am trying to implement the second solution but as I mentioned earlier but again, how should I initialize the samplerCube ? Should I have 6 textures of 1x1px loaded as a cubemap in the GPU memory and when I want to initialize the uniforms in my shaders, then send that "empty" cubemap sent, or is there a more fancy way of doing so (having a sampler giving only (0,0,0,1) ) ?

Comment: If `pointLights[]` is a uniform, what prevents you from initializating it on CPU side with 0 or 1 right before passing it to the GPU?

Comment: Uniform are by default initialized by 0.

Comment: "*in order to avoid branching*" Why are you trying to avoid a static branch? Do you think it will [make your code faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37827216/734069)?

Comment: Oh thank you Nicol Bolas, I heard about that branching problem and never tried to dig further into it, did not know about all the details your answer provides.