# Passing functions to shaders?

Tags: glsl, hlsl, spir-v

I am building a small machine learning implementation using compute shaders and I want to pass an array of activation functions indexed to each workgroup/invocation through an SSBO because writing an if-else/switch statement for each invocation would become problematic very quickly.

C/C++ allows functions to be passed into others by passing a pointer to the function and then dereferencing it:

```cpp
void foo(int input);

void bar(int input, void(*foo)(int)) {
    *foo(input);
}
//Side note, it is not necessary for me that the function is a void function,
// it can return an int, double, float, etc.
```

However, I don’t think this exact implementation can be done with shaders since the data "lives" on the GPU, so pointers to memory on the CPU might not be a valid method.

So, is it possible to pass functions to a compute shader (GLSL, HLSL, or SPIR-V) in a storage buffer or via some other method? I am currently using the Vulkan framework, but I am open to implementations using other computer graphics frameworks.

Comment: Assuming I understand your question correctly, I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467358/glsl-function-pointer-or-equivalent. TL;DR: GLSL and SPIR-V don't have function pointers.

Comment: It's possible. Subroutines look about right. For some clarification, my idea was to define the functions on the CPU side (return type `int` for this example) and pack them into a `std::vector` then load them into an SSBO and access them in the shader with something like `layout (binding = 0) buffer SSBO { int funcs[];};` and then execute them per invocation with `int output = funcs[invocationIndexer](/*args*/);` where `invocationIndexer` just creates a unique index for each `gl_InvocationID`.

Comment: Given that the `std::vector` container stores function contents via pointers, then you're probably right and that thread would answer my question.

Comment: Can't you just generate the source with the desired function?

Comment: @gre_gor how do you mean, like just define all of the functions in the shader file? I guess I never really thought about it that way. Afterall, the memory defining the functions would be used up somewhere.